# If a string includes a user defined "value", how do you return the full content of the string?

Tags: c#, string, contains

I'm essentially looking for a glorified autocomplete, where a user can input a search term and have all strings that include that word, in any position in their string, be returned to the user.

This is what I have currently:

```
    void Start()
    {

        string SearchTerm = "museum"; //Example text 

        List<string> Museums = new List<string>() {
            "the aquarium",
            "the british museum",
            "the german museum",
            "natural history building",
            "glasgow science room"
        };

        if (Museums.Any(str => str.Contains(SearchTerm)))
        {
            //print(MatchingValues.From.Museums)
            //IE would print "the british museum","the german museum"

        else
        {
            print("None found, search again");
        }
    }
```

I'm quite new to this so I'm not sure what terms I should be using for it to return the values I want, unfortunately.

Comment: I recommend using regex.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Linq

Include

```
using System.Linq;
```

And change your code to

```
var searchTerm = "museum";

var museums = new List<string>() {
    "the aquarium",
    "the british museum",
    "the german museum",
    "natural history building",
    "glasgow science room"
};

var results = museums.Where(r => r.Contains(searchTerm)).ToList();
```

You can now use `results` to print out the values or anything else you need to do

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
void Start()
    {

        string SearchTerm = "museum"; //Example text 

        List<string> Museums = new List<string>() {
            "the aquarium",
            "the british museum",
            "the german museum",
            "natural history building",
            "glasgow science room"
        };

        if (Museums.Any(str => str.Contains(SearchTerm)))
        {
            Museums.ForEach(delegate(String museum)
            {
                if (museum.Contains(SearchTerm))
                {
                    print(museum)
                }
            });

        else
        {
            print("None found, search again");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Enumerable.Where](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=netframework-4.8) to filter the list based on search term.

```
if (Museums.Any(str => str.Contains(SearchTerm)))
{
    foreach(var museum in Museums.Where(str => str.Contains(SearchTerm)))
        print(museum);
}
else
{
    print("None found, search again");
}
```

I assume print has been defined else where in your code.

If you want to make your search case-insensitive, you could use [string.IndexOf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?view=netframework-4.8#System_String_IndexOf_System_String_System_Int32_System_StringComparison_) method

```
if (Museums.Any(str => str.IndexOf(SearchTerm, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)!=-1))
{
    foreach(var museum in Museums.Where(str => str.IndexOf(SearchTerm, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)!=-1))
            print(museum);
}
else
{
    print("None found, search again");
}
```

You could make the code more readable by creating an [Extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) for Contains that supports case-insensitive comparisons. For example,

```
public static class Extensions
{
  public static bool Contains(this string source, string searchTerm, StringComparison comparison)
  {
    return searchTerm != null && source?.IndexOf(searchTerm, comparison) >= 0;
  }
}
```

Now you could use it as

```
if (Museums.Any(str => str.Contains(SearchTerm, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)))
{
   foreach(var museum in Museums.Where(str => str.Contains(SearchTerm, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)))
        print(museum);
}
else
{
        print("None found, search again");
}
```